# Some JVM monitoring checks via SNMP return zero values in JVM 1.8

Tags: java, java-8, snmp, oid

My monitoring tools uses SNMP to get several internal values of Java Virtual Machines 1.6 and 1.7. The problem is that some values in JVM 1.8 machines return a zero value.

These are **`NoHeapMemPoolMaxSize`** (OID: .3.163.1.1.2.23.0) and **`PoolMaxSize`** (OID: .3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13.2). The snmpwalk output:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.900.3.163.1.1.2.23.0 = Counter64: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.900.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13.2 = Counter64: 0
```

Have changed the OIDs of these both values? I compared **JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib** for [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib) and [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib) and I have found no difference.

What is wrong here?

Comment: According to the MIB, `42.2.900` should be `42.2.145`, and the names are `jvmMemoryNonHeapMaxSize` and `jvmMemPoolMaxSize.2`. The latter has an index which "is not guaranteed to stay identical after the agent restarts", so the value you want might be in another row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the JVM had not defined the ***maximum MetaSpace size***. After adding **`-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m`** as a command line argument, the snmpwalk command shows that those values are no longer zero:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.900.3.163.1.1.2.23.0 = Counter64: 1593835520
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.900.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13.2 = Counter64: 268435456
```

Best regards.